# How should I manage this scenario in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, frontend

I'm developing a React app and somewhere user has to select a character:

- comma (,)
- semicolon (;)
- colon (:)
- Other

When user selects 'Other' a new input shows up and allows user to text a custom character.

Now, I'm doing something like this:

```
const characters = [",", ";", ":", "Other"]

function MyComponent() {

   const [character, setCharacter] = useState(',');
   const [otherCharacter, setOtherCharacter] = useState('');

   return <div>
     <Dropdown items={characters} itemSelected={character} onItemChanged={setCharacter} />
     {character === 'Other' && <input value={otherCharacter} onChange={e => setOtherCharacter(e.target.value)}>}
     <button text="Do Something" onClick={() => {
         let ch = character;
         if (character === 'Other') {
           ch = otherCharacter;
         }
         doSomething(ch);
     }} />
   </div>

}

...

function doSomething(character) {
  //TODO
}
```

As you see, I need to use two states (`useState`) to manage it. I wonder if there is some pattern or best practice to deal with this in React.

Comment: What you currently have seems like a reasonable approach

Comment: I agree with @mousetail

Comment: Cool. It seems the way to go then. I will close the question. Thank you!

Comment: My only suggestion would be a ***very*** minor change to how you grab the character in the click handler: `const ch = character === "Other" ? otherCharacter : character;` (if you do that more than one place, put it in a reusable function). I'm not 100% happy with holding `"Other"` in `character`, but having explored the alternative of holding a flag in another state member, it just complicates things.

Comment: Thank you. I think I'm going to develop a hook for this. Something like `const [selectedCharacter, isCustom, selectCharacter] = useCharacters(characters)` would be interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More cleaner code

```
const OTHER_CHAR = 'Other';
const characters = [",", ";", ":", OTHER_CHAR]

function submitCallback(char) {
    //TODO
}

function MyComponent() {

   const [character, setCharacter] = useState(',');
   const [otherCharacter, setOtherCharacter] = useState('');

   const isOtherCharacter = character === OTHER_CHAR;

   const onSubmit = () => {
        let ch = character;
        if (character === OTHER_CHAR) {
            ch = otherCharacter;
        }
        submitCallback(ch);
    }

   return <div>
     <Dropdown items={characters} itemSelected={character} onItemChanged={setCharacter} />
     {isOtherCharacter && <input value={otherCharacter} onChange={e => setOtherCharacter(e.target.value)} />}
     <button text="Do Something" onClick={onSubmit} />
   </div>
}
```

Or you can even pass submitCallback as the prop to the component

```
function MyComponent({submitCallback }) {
...
}
```

UPDATE ===========

You can avoid  reassigning the character to ch:

```
const onSubmit = () => {
  if (character === OTHER_CHAR) {
    submitCallback(otherCharacter);
  } else {
    submitCallback(character);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Not too much improvement but this will short some line of code

```
const onSubmit = () => {
  submitCallback(character !== 'Other'? character: otherCharacter);
}
```

Comment: I think this wouldn't work because, when user types something in "other" input and then he selects another option, `otherCharacter` still have value.